# Access Spark Hive metastore within an UDF running in the workers (Databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, databricks, metastore

**Context**

I have an operation that should be performed on some tables using pyspark.
This operation includes accessing the Spark metastore (in Databricks) to get some metadata.
Since I have plenty of tables I'm **parallelizing** this operation among the cluster workers with an **RDD**, as you can see in the code below:

```py
    base_spark_context = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    rdd = base_spark_context.sc.parallelize(tables_list)
    rdd.map(lambda table_name: sync_table(table_name)).collect()
```

The UDF `sync_table()` run queries on the metastore, similar to this code line:

```py
spark_client.session.sql("select 1")
```

**Problem**
The problem is that this SQL execution not succeeds. Rather I get some metastore related error. Traceback:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o20.sql.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

(suppressed lines)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

(suppressed lines)

Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@16c0663d, see the next exception for details.

(suppressed lines)

Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /databricks/spark/work/app-20210413201900-0000/0/metastore_db.
```

Is there any limitation accessing the Databricks metastore within a worker, after parallelizing the operation in such a way? Or there is a possibility of performing such an operation?

Comment: what do you want to achive at the end? Why not use just thread pool to parallelize queries?

Comment: @AlexOtt the goal is to run that hundred tables synchronization in parallel. I know that running it in the driver through python multiprocessing is an option. But I first wanted to take advantage of the cluster distributed parallelism.

Comment: The problem is that Spark config is not automatically distributed to worker nodes... you can try to enforce it from UDF itself, but needs testing